# Cross Browser Overflow moz-hidden-unscrollable for ContentEditable

Tags: jquery, html, css, contenteditable

Is there a way to achieve overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable in a cross browser (IE 9+, modern browsers) fashion?

When I set a height on a contenteditable div, the overflow forces the previous lines of text up -- scrolling the div container down and the content up. I need for the existing content to remain and have the content below hidden.

-moz-hidden-unscrollable is the effect I am going for, but it does not work in all the modern browsers + IE 9.

```
div {
    height:14px;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The goal is that a user can type in the div and hit enter for a new line, but the Y overflow should be hidden and the div not scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyown5g1/

Comment: This would make it pretty much impossible to know what's actually inside the element, no?  Without arrowing around in a horrible fashion?

Comment: The application handles the overflow by showing a warning. That's not the issue. It's the content above that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your JSFiddle with a possible solution. It adds an event handler for the `scroll` event and resets the y offset every time the event is fired (in this case, a new line is made).

jQuery:

```
var formerY = 0;

$("div").on("scroll", function(e){
    $(e.target).scrollTop(formerY);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cyown5g1/1/

Comment: For higher specificity, yes. But in this case there is only one `div` and OP can easily adjust it. For the sake of a simple example I think it's fine. The real worry would be if OP was using generic, non-specific selectors like this in his production code (instead of a `class`, `id`, etc.)

Comment: I just said "should", I didn't said "It must be like this or your code is garbage!". The difference is huge. But your code works, and that's what matters. But, if you want a full implementation with style checking, you would need to do something like this pseudo-code: `$("[contenteditable]").( "scroll",  function(){ if( this.style.overflow == 'hidden'){ this.scrollTop(0); } } );`.

Comment: Yes the div selector is just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's all semantics at this point, and it assumes a lot about the poster's desires and intentions that you we don't know. How do you know he wants to target all `contentEditable` `divs`, or even only the ones with `overflow: hidden`? (Which, by the way, your example only addresses inline CSS) My answer was intended to give the poster a springboard and example of concept. It's pointless of you or I to guess at what code would be best for without knowing what he's trying to do...?

Comment: That was just pseudo-code.Look, I',m not saying that you are wrong. I'm showing you a way to solve partially the problem. If that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2021:

The new value for overflow, `clip`, is being adopted by all major browsers which will essentially do the same thing that `-moz-hidden-unscrollable`

From mozilla's own post:

> We intend to ship CSS overflow:clip in v81, which is the standardized
> version of a prefixed value (-moz-hidden-unscrollable) that we already
> ship. The prefixed value becomes an alias for the new value.
> The standardized value is mostly compatible, but there are some
> differences. Most notably, we now support clipping in one axis
> and overflowing in the other (i.e. 'clip' can be combined with
> 'visible' in the overflow-x/y properties).

References:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-clip
- https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/7oQm8PC0aU0?pli=1
- https://chromestatus.com/feature/5638444178997248

Comment: "is being adopted" ... Apple as of 2021: hold my beer.